# How did I crash in a @try/@catch block?

Tags: ios, exception

I received the following crash report (truncated)

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36df00d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31760674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31f2338a CFRunLoopWakeUp + 50
3   WebCore                         0x308d0bc8 _WebThreadRun + 284
4   UIKit                           0x37921c7a -[UIWebDocumentView _runLoadBlock:] + 38
5   UIKit                           0x37921c3a -[UIWebDocumentView _cleanUpFrameStateAndLoad:] + 114
6   UIKit                           0x37921bbe -[UIWebDocumentView loadHTMLString:baseURL:] + 78
```

The concern is that the calling code looks like this:

```
@try {
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    [webView setNeedsDisplay];     
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {...}
```

So, how did I manage to throw an exception from within an exception handler?

I didn't call the throwing method from inside catch. All I'm doing there is dumping to NSLog the exception, the webView, and the htmlString. If they were causing the exception I would expect the crash stack to look differently.

Does this seem to reduce into a potential OS bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a **segmentation fault (SIGSEGV)**, not an exception.

Those faults aren't exceptions, meaning you can't use a try/catch block.

A segmentation fault means you are trying to access a memory region that doesn't belong to your app.

In your case, it may be cause be auto-released objects that gets deallocated, and then accessed (the pointer is not valid anymore, since the object was deallocated).

Ensure your `htmlString` variable is still pointing to a valid object...

By the way, I don't think calling `setNeedsDisplay` is needed after using `loadHTMLString`.

Comment: Okay... That makes sense. The call is in a function that may be called from a dying thread. I've protected the method to make sure it calls itself on the main thread. This doesn't guarantee that the string sent to it survives the threaded caller ending and cleaning itself up. Thanks specifically for this. I thought that segfaults could be caught with exception handling. I appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: Segmentation faults are signals, send by the OS to the application. They can be "caught" by a signal handler (see the signal() C function). A segmentation fault can be managed by a signal handler, even if it's usually not a good idea to do so, except for debugging, as it will leave the app in an inconsistent state.